# Can I run a remote X session in windowed mode?

Tags: remote-x-session

I want to run a remote X session in windowed mode. I cannot find any help in the Manual of X, nor in the internet.

Does anyone know how to do that?
By now I'm doing: `X :2 -query hostname`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xnest should be your friend here. Install the `xnest` package and use

```
Xnest -query hostname
```

Comment: I already tried Xnest out. It crashed pretty randomly and I need this for work. Thanks anyway! Other suggestions?

Comment: OK, it's been a while (years) that I used Xnest. It seems that Xnest isn't up to date any more, I does not support every extension for X that is available now. A more up to date solution seems to be `Xephyr` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/Xephyr.1.html) - basically the same as Xnest with more extensions. Haven't tried this.

Comment: I already tried that out as well ;) Problem here is: keyboard arrow keys don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem! Thanks to Thomas!
Xephyr did, what i needed!

And for anyone who has problems with some keys not working, add following option to Xephyr:

`-keybd ephyr,,,xkbmodel=evdev`

So my command looks like this now:

`Xephyr :2 -keybd ephyr,,,xkbmodel=evdev -query hostname`

Good luck!